# MVC adjust linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model like below:

```
public class tblListing
{
    [Key]
    public int lngListingId { get; set; }
    public int lngCatId { get; set; }
    public int lngUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblCategory> Category { get; set; }
    public virtual tblUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Category Model:

```
public class tblCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int lngCatId { get; set; }
    public string txtTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var listing = db.Listing
                  .Include(s => s.User)
                  .Include(s => s.Category);
    return View(listing.ToList());
}
```

The problem is in the View it display all columns from User model but does not display anything from Category.

What should be changed in linq query or how to resolve the problem?

Comment: How is `tblCategory` related to `tblListing` (`tblCategory` does not contain a property for the FK relationship)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it should not be mandatory to specify the other side of the relationship, EF can generate the FK. OP, could you show how the view looks like? Or at least the relevant parts?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it is related with lngCatId.

Comment: No, that's the PK of your `tblCategory` objects. You would need a `lngListingId` field in `tblCategory` (and your `lngCatId` property in `tblListing` makes no sense - that would only be meaningful if `tblListing` has one `tblCategory` object, not a collection).

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hmm... Okay. I understand. Thanks!